# Cohomology of geometric realization of a simplicial topological space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-stuff

Let $X$ be a simplicial topological space. We can consider to notions of cohomology of $X$.

- Denote by $|X|$ geometric realization of $X$. Then we can take just $H^*(|X| )$ (i.e. usual cohomology of $|X|$).
- We can compose $X$ and functor of simplicial chains $C_* \circ X$, and we get a simplicial complex (for safety it is better consider rational coefficients). Via Dold-Kan correspondence we get a double complex $DK( C_* \circ X )$. Finally you consider total complex of this double complex $Tot \ DK(  C_* \circ X )$ and count cohomology.

**Question:** Do these notions coincide?

I am not looking for pathological counterexamples. If it is needed to add some sensible assumptions, then do it.

Comment: I tried to write an answer but there are too many problems with your question: 1/ cohomology is contravariant, so you get a **co**simplicial thing; 2/ $H^*(Z)$ is a graded abelian group when $Z$ is a topological space, so what you get in the end is a cosimplicial graded abelian group. There's a spectral sequence here, but it's not really directly applicable to your question.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi I edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: I believe the answer is "yes" (I'm more confident for the corresponding statement about homology, but I think this is ok too). Non-elementary proof: C_* commutes with homotopy colimits. Elementary proof: maybe use that there is a map between both objects and a spectral sequence computing their homology that has the same E_2 term?